# How to get the facebook username in wordpress facebook all plugin?

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook all plugin for facebook login in wordpress, but it is not retrieving the username, instead of username it is appending  the firstname and lastname. how can i get the exact username?

```
$fbdata = facebookall_get_fbuserprofile_data($fbuser_info);
    if (!empty($fbdata['email']) AND !empty($fbdata['id'])) {
      // Filter username form data.
      if(!empty($fbdata['name'])) {
        $username = $fbdata['name'];
      }
      else if (!empty($fbdata['first_name']) && !empty($fbdata['last_name'])) {
        $username = $fbdata['first_name'].$fbdata['last_name'];
      }
      else {        $user_emailname = explode('@', $fbdata['email']);
        $username = $user_emailname[0];
      }
```

Comment: The field `username` is what you are looking for, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: yes, so i will get the username right?, so i can avoid duplication

Answer (score 0):

username is `$current_user->user_login` so you need

```
$username = $current_user->user_login;
```